# CSS challenge: jQuery's slideDown-like on a specific particular layout

Tags: jquery, css, layout, slidetoggle

I'm looking for a classic jQuery's `slideDown`-like, but I can't find a solution that suits the layout I need:

[image: Expected output]

When a red corner gets clicked, I need the corresponding orange box to appear in a *jQuery's `slideDown` way*. The red corner must slides down too with the orange box, just as if it were not fastened to the yellow box, but rather with the orange one. Thus, where the red corner initially was, the background gets actually orange as well, to emphasize the effect. Of course, when a red corner gets re-clicked, the orange box must slides up, and the red corner fits its original location back (`toggle`-like).

I tried some tricks using `z-index`, `overflow:hidden`, etc., but I have to admit that I'm totally stuck with this CSS technical challenge...

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qdc7n/) you can play with ;)

Comment: Make the "orange box" contain the bottom of the top box, position it correctly over the yellow box but hidden, have the red triangle be positioned absolutely within the "orange box" attached to the bottom, then animate the height of the "orange box" to the desired height. Make an attempt at solving it and i'll help.

Comment: Here's what I came up with: http://jsfiddle.net/qdc7n/1/

Comment: And then keeping the orange triangle: http://jsfiddle.net/qdc7n/2/

Comment: making the orange triangle clickable though is difficult.

Comment: @KevinB You're upvoted solution is exactly what I needed, awesome! Put it as an answer so I can validate it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a wrapper for the bottom section of the box that contains the toggle and the message, set the height of the wrapper to the height of the toggle, then position the message below that out of view. Then, add another div to be the orange triangle to the li so that it will be behind the red triangle and message box. Finally, on click, simply animate toggle the height and bottom position of the wrapper.

html:

```
<ul>
    <li><div class="triangle"></div><div class="pop"><div class="toggle"></div><div class="orange">Hello World!</div></div></li>
    ...
```

javascript:

```
$('.toggle').click(function() {
    $parent = $(this).parent();
    if ($parent.data("flag")) {
        $parent.data("flag",false);
        $parent.animate({height:"30px",bottom:"0"});
    }
    else {
        $parent.data("flag",true);
        $parent.animate({height:"90px",bottom:"-60px"});
    }
});
```

css:

```
.pop {
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 99;
}
.toggle {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 30px 30px;
    border-color: transparent transparent red transparent;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 99;
}
.triangle {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 30px 30px;
    border-color: transparent transparent orange transparent;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 99;
}
.orange {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qdc7n/2/

Comment: Many thanks, I'm not sure I would have find this solution on my own.

Comment: Hi great solution can you explain me a little the `.data` you use

Comment: the way i'm using .data is similar to declaring a flag variable outside that gets switched from true to false back and forth. It's simply a way of storing what state the box is currently in. A global var wouldn't work because there's more than one element being handled by the click event.

Answer (score 2):

Alright I was able to ahcieve this with only `css`, `html`, and `jQuery`.

First how I am structuring the `html`,

```
<li class="content-box">
    <div class="slide">
        <span class="red-tri"></span>
        <span class="slide-info">
            I was hidden!
        </span>
    </div>
</li>
```

Next the `css` to create the effect,

```
.content-box {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   background: yellow;
   margin: 20px auto;
   position: relative;
}

.red-tri {
   border-bottom: 30px solid red;
   border-left: 30px solid transparent;
   border-right: 0 solid transparent;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
}

.slide {
   transition: all 0.6s ease;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
   -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
   -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease;
   -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   display: block;
   top: 0;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 100;
}

.slide.active {
   background: #ff9900;
   top: 100%;
   height: 50px;
   z-index: 110;
}

.slide.active:after {
   content: "";
   border-bottom: 30px solid #ff9900;
   border-left: 30px solid transparent;
   border-right: 0 solid transparent;
   position: absolute;
   top: -30px;
   right: 0;
}

.slide-info {
   display: none;
}

.slide-info.active {
   display: block;
}
```

Lastly, the little bit of jQuery,

```
$('.red-tri').on('click', function() {
   $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
   $(this).parent().find('.slide-info').toggleClass('active')
});
```

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_JM/dsSbt/6/) to see how the effect is.

Comment: Thank you Josh. You're solution looks good too, but I have to admit that @Kevin's one is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: No problem, best of luck in your design mate.